# How to apply vat tax rule for all products on site

Tags: magento

Is there anybody knows how to do this without touch database? Many thanks for any answer.

Comment: please say what you have tried so far

Comment: A have setup vat rule, now I need apply this rule to all products, by default I can do this when I edit price tab in product by setup vat rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution. Go to Catalog->Products, in table that display product choose "Select All" and then go to "Actions" and choose update "Update Attributes" and click "Submit". Then set Tax class value from selectbox. That it.

Answer (score 0):

Andrey, I suggest you to go through with this http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/setting-up-value-added-tax-vat .

it's official document of magento and they have explain, tax rule nicely. hope it will help you

Comment: No, question not about how to create this rule, question is how to apply this rule to all products?

Comment: either modify all the products or create a php script to do the same for you.